# How to implement swipe to select? Similar to the Photos app on iOS

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to wrap multiple cards with a gesture detector to be able to select individual cards on either a tab on a card or on a right swipe over one or multiple cards.

A similar functionality is implemented for the selection of Photos in the photos app on iOS:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this package [drag_select_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/drag_select_grid_view):

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final controller = DragSelectGridViewController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller.addListener(scheduleRebuild);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.removeListener(scheduleRebuild);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: SelectionAppBar(
        selection: controller.value,
      ),
      body: DragSelectGridView(
        gridController: controller,
        itemCount: 20,
        itemBuilder: (context, index, selected) {
          return SelectableItem(
            index: index,
            selected: selected,
          );
        },
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
          maxCrossAxisExtent: 80,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void scheduleRebuild() => setState(() {});
}
```